# $\int_a^b|f|d\alpha = 0$ for some continuous $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Construct a nonconstant increasing function $\alpha$ and nonzero continuous function $f\in R_\alpha[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b|f|d\alpha=0$. Is it possible for $\alpha$ to be continuous？

Question from Carothers's Real Analysis. I have no I idea how to approach this. My gut feeling is that this is not possible since if $f$ is non-zero and continuous, $|f| > 0$. Thus, for any partition, we have $L(f, P) = \sum_i m_i\Delta\alpha_i$ where $m_i > 0$ and $\Delta\alpha_i > 0$ for at least some i. Thus, this may contradict with $\int_a^b|f|d\alpha=0$. However, I'm not sure how does continuous plays a role here.

Comment: Instead of looking at the theory, try to use the properties of the R-S integral. For example, try taking a look at the properties wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral. Can you construct a satisfactory example now?

Comment: @PCeltide Thank you for the hint, but I'm still unsure how to do the construct (specifically I don't have a nice function on top of my head to use those properties). Do you mind take it a bit further?

Comment: Is increasing for you the same thing as strictly increasing? Otherwise, it is helpful to consider some $\alpha$ that is zero on some interval and then construct $f$ in a suitable way.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Sorry, I still can't see how to achieve while forcing $\alpha$ to be continuous at the same time.

Comment: If you have $\alpha=1$ on $[0,2/3]$ and $f=0$ on $[1/2]$, then $\int_0^1 \vert f\vert d\alpha=0$ independent of what $\alpha$ is equal to on $[2/3,1]$. Can you show that? Then generalize.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I see your point, thanks for the advice. I thought nonzero to be a stronger condition that f cannot be zero on all of its domain (the Carothers book is really unclear regarding the wording).

Comment: Your interpretation does not work, as we would have $\vert f(x) \vert \geq c>0$ and hence, $\int_a^b \vert f \vert d\alpha \geq \int_a^b c d\alpha =c (\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))>0$.